# Compute Erf(z) using Fresnel integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fresnel-integrals

I have to compute $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ using the Fresnel integrals. I have the relation:

$$C(z)+iS(z)=\frac{1+i}{2}\operatorname{erf}\left[ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(1-i)z \right].$$

But $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ has a complex argument. I've tried to make it real, but I didn't get a correct relation.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This page gives you other information which could be useful (in particular for S + i C)     (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)